# Issue in verifying google captcha in angularjs with nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I am trying to verify the login with google captcha in angularjs with nodejs server, when i try to login with re-captcha i am getting http error 405 not found, and when i login without captcha verification i get the following errors in browser console -

```
base.js:5 ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://192.168.1.23:8080/app/js/app.js:1006:15)
    at Object.i [as invoke] (http://192.168.1.23:8080/app/js/base.js:4:17991)
    at f.instance (http://192.168.1.23:8080/app/js/base.js:5:6796)
    at http://192.168.1.23:8080/app/js/base.js:4:29565
    at o (http://192.168.1.23:8080/app/js/base.js:4:903)
    at b (http://192.168.1.23:8080/app/js/base.js:4:29549)
    at s (http://192.168.1.23:8080/app/js/base.js:4:25618)
    at http://192.168.1.23:8080/app/js/base.js:4:25114
    at http://192.168.1.23:8080/app/js/base.js:13:22101
    at oe (http://192.168.1.23:8080/app/js/base.js:5:3727) 

<div ui-view="" autoscroll="false" class="ng-zoomBackDown ng-fluid ng-scope">
```

And when i try to login with verifying i get an error 405.

login.html

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#comment_form').submit(function() {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
          error: function(xhr) {
            status('Error: ' + xhr.status);
          },
         success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
         }
        });
        //Very important line, it disable the page refresh.
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
```

access-login-js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));

app.get('/',function(req,res) {
  // Sending our HTML file to browser.
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/login.html');
});

app.post('/submit',function(req,res){
  // g-recaptcha-response is the key that browser will generate upon form submit.
  // if its blank or null means user has not selected the captcha, so return the error.
  if(req.body['g-recaptcha-response'] === undefined || req.body['g-recaptcha-response'] === '' || req.body['g-recaptcha-response'] === null) {
    return res.json({"responseCode" : 1,"responseDesc" : "Please select captcha"});
  }
  // Put your secret key here.
  var secretKey = "my_key_here";
  // req.connection.remoteAddress will provide IP address of connected user.
  var verificationUrl = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" + secretKey + "&response=" + req.body['g-recaptcha-response'] + "&remoteip=" + req.connection.remoteAddress;
  // Hitting GET request to the URL, Google will respond with success or error scenario.
  request(verificationUrl,function(error,response,body) {
    body = JSON.parse(body);
    // Success will be true or false depending upon captcha validation.
    if(body.success !== undefined && !body.success) {
      return res.json({"responseCode" : 1,"responseDesc" : "Failed captcha verification"});
    }
    res.json({"responseCode" : 0,"responseDesc" : "Sucess"});
  });
});

// This will handle 404 requests.
app.use("*",function(req,res) {
  res.status(404).send("404");
})

// lifting the app on port 3000.
app.listen(3000);


}]);
```